# How can I write data to a database table on another server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) line to connect to another server through php. I am trying to write to a MySQL database.

I have used the server's IP [A.B.C.D] on the $host variable. However I cannot write to that database, and the script does not run completely.

I am using the root user and password to connect, and the user list in phpmyadmin shows that anyhost(%), 127.0.0.1 and localhost can connect with the root username (I think that's what it means). Anyway, as I am using root, I don't think this is a user privilege problem.

I have tried putting a # before 'bind-address=127.0.0.1'.

I have tried editing my.cnf according to suggestions from a lot of forums.

I have not installed firewall in any of the servers that I'm using, so unless Debian 7 64-bit comes with pre-installed firewall that blocks certain ports, I don't think that is the problem either.

Isn't there an easy way to establish connection between multiple servers? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote mysql server must accept remote connection from your IP address.

After you make this setup you can access remote mysql server like this:

```
mysqli_connect($remote_host, $remote_user, $pemote_pass, $remote_db);
```

Comment: How do I make sure that it accepts remote connections? I've found somewhere that I have to edit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file. But what are the exact changes that I need to make? Also, do I edit this file on the local machine? Or the remote machine? I'm really confused!

Comment: here you have a complete tutorial how to do that.  http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm

Comment: Remote server is your "other server". you have to edit that my.cnf   file to accept connection from your ip.

Comment: I tried to follow your debianhelp.co.uk link and my mysql will not restart! Kill me now !!!! >.< Is xampp easier to manage? I've got Access Forbidden error when I installed XAMPP. I don't know which way to go.. lol..

Comment: Do you have access to remote now?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm reinstalling the OS on both servers right now. Going with Debian 7 64-bit (trying to see if that makes any difference). I guess my problem now is to restart MySQL. Is this a problem for Linux servers? Or does Windows Servers have similar remote connection problems?

Comment: Finally got it to work, but the connection is a bit slow. No worries, I guess it's because of the VPS I rented, will get a better one. I use d the Remote Server's IP on bind-address.. all this time I was using the Local Server's IP.. thanks for the article Florin.. :)

Comment: Solved the slow connection. In my remote server--> # nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf... under the [mysqld] section added the line--> skip-name-resolve

I love this community! :D